# jquery: merge XML documents

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, jquery

is it possible to **merge multiple xmlDocuments into one single file (var newResult)** by using jquery (or pure javascript) ?

unfortunately i've to combine different hosted xml-documents into one single file (don't ask me why...). i've played around with different techniques, but i can't find a solution for this (maybe jquery isn't ready for xml-handling??). thank you :)

see my piece of code:

```
var files = ['john.xml','doe.xml']
var newResult, temp;

function loadMyXMLFiles(){

    // > let's load file by file using jquery's ajax-call:

    $.each(files, function(index,value) { 

      $.ajax({

          url: value,
          cache: true,
          success: function(data){

            // > check if temp is empty, append or fill

            (temp) ? temp += (data) : temp = data;


            // > on complete:

            if (index == files.length-1) {

                xmlResult = temp; temp = null;
            }
          }

      });
  });
}

loadMyXMLFiles()
```

[image]

Comment: If you add 'dataType: "xml"' to your ajax call, jquery parse the xml for you into a dom tree. Then you can recursive merge the tree with the existing tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see, you are trying to concatenate them. If this is what you need, your code wasn't that bad,

```
var files = ['john.xml','doe.xml']
var xmlResult, temp = ""; //Make temp an empty string

loadMyXMLFiles(){
    $.each(files, function(index,value) { 
      $.ajax({
          url: value,
          cache: true,
          async: false, //This is crucial!
          success: function(data){
            temp += data;
            if (index == files.length-1) {
                xmlResult = temp; temp = null;
            }
          }
      });
  });
}
```

You have to use `async: false` so your files arrive in order. But caution, this will hang the browser until the processing is finished. If it's vital for it not to happen, just tell me.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Why use async false? You're creating an anonymous function and could just pass in the index, which would remain constant (Closures 'n all), right? Using a little counter and another callback you could then process them in order when they're all asynchronously loaded.

Comment: my result for "temp" returns: "[object XMLDocument][object XMLDocument][object XMLDocument]" but the correct result should be "Document" - what's wrong ?

Comment: @Alexander, exactly, I would have given a solution similar to that if msec requested it, it all depends on his needs.

Comment: @msec. To avoid that, add a `dataType: 'text',` parameter in your ajax call.

Comment: `temp+=data` should probably be `temp.appendChild(data)`. Otherwise you're just slamming objects together and not merging the actualy XML. Or your solution made 9 sec. earlier, but that would kill off manipulative capabilities.

Comment: appendChild(data) seems to be only available for dom objects. does anybody else got another idea/solution for merging xml-documents?